# How to preserve anchor links when pasting from Word into CKeditor?

Tags: 8

Microsoft Word documents often include a table of contents which link to anchor tags elsewhere in the file.

When pasting from Word into ckeditor using the full_html text format I find that the resulting anchors are wrapped in  tags but an id attribute is not present.

```
<a>Introduction</a>
```

I would have expected something like this

```
<a href="#_Toc45634158">Introduction</a>
```

Or this

```
<a href="#_Toc45634158"></a>Introduction
```

When manually entered in the source code using the full_html text format the anchor link still does not work.

There appear to be two things going on.

1. The paste from Word functionallity is stripping the ID value from the link
2. Without additional configuration, anchor tags don't appear to work with the full_html text format

How to solve both problems?

Comment: I think it's realted to the CKEditor ACF filter https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/guide/dev_acf.html, you could try to configure it on the drupal side

Comment: Thank Yuriy. I'll read up on that.